# Two ul li not being inline using css

Tags: html, css

im very new at this, was practising copying some sites and got stuck with creating the header. 
As one ul they sit inline but when I add another ul they stack inline. Eventually id float left and set a class to one to float the other to the right but at the moment they end up not being on the same line.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>html</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="try.css">
</head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Five</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Six</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Seven</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

header nav ul li {
display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `ul` is a `block` element. It means it will occupy 100% of the document width.

You have to change his default behavior to `display: inline` to make it works.

**OR** a better way is to use only one `ul` with all your `li` elements in it.

[First solution](https://jsfiddle.net/6yny11cy/1/)

```
header nav ul { 
  display: inline;
}
```

[Second solution](https://jsfiddle.net/6yny11cy/2/)

```
<body>

    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Five</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Six</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Seven</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

</body>
```

Comment: No luck, removing li doesn't work. And second solution youve grouped the ul? after i will float 123 to the left and 4567 to the right so surly i need two ul so i can at least set one as a class to move to the right? soon as i add the second ul they stack ontop of each other in two inlines.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Float one to the left and one to the right ?

Comment: I'm after two separate ul but both to be inline. inline works with one ul but soon as i add another they split one above the other. which confuses me as shouldn't header nav ul li work for all regardless how many ul?

Comment: No. Did you read my first solution ? ul is a block element by default so you have to put it also in inline type, like you did with li elements.